# WCF Service Web Role: ODATA filtering on C# in-memory schemas

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, odata

Is it possible to do `ODATA` filtering on `C# in-memory schemas`? Actually, I have a `WCF Service based Azure Web Role` which expose some modeled data in form of `JSON` through `REST based API`. Now, I want to add support for filtered data as well on the bases of some fields or count. I came across `ODATA` which looks good for my requirements but the problem I'm facing that on internet everybody is talking about `ODATA as WCF Data Service`. So, my doubt is that whether it is possible to use`Odata` in this case? Also, is there any library which supports such kind of requirement?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ODATA with Web Api too and you can host your web api as self host.

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/self-host-a-web-api

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api